# Some doubts about positional and keyword way to pass arguments to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following question from the exercise related to a certification.

I have this simple function:

```
def fun(a,b):
    return a + b
```

that is called by:

```
res = fun(1,2)
```

On the study materials give the following answer to the question "what is the way to passing arguments": **keywords**.

In my opinion this answer is wrong because, according to: https://www.techbeamers.com/python-function/

the keywords way should imply something like this:

```
res = fun(a=1, b=2)
```

Is it my reasoning correct?

The other options are:

- named
- positional
- sequential

My idea is that in this case is positional.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The "official" line is here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions. It seems like the certification is not a good one, keyword/named and positional/sequential are really just two answers, and the second pair is the one that correctly describes how those arguments are being passed.

Answer (score -1):

The answer given by the tutorial is right in so far they are *both* positional **and** keyword parameters. Consider the following example:

```py
>>> def f(a,b):
        print(a) 
>>> f(2,3)
2
>>> f(b=3, a=2)
2
```

From the [Python Glossary (parameter)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter):

> A named entity in a function (or method) definition that specifies an argument (or in some cases, arguments) that the function can accept. There are five kinds of parameter:
>
> - positional-or-keyword: specifies an argument that can be passed either positionally or as a keyword argument. This is the default kind of parameter, for example foo and bar in the following:
>
>   `def func(foo, bar=None): ...`
> - positional-only: specifies an argument that can be supplied only by position. Python has no syntax for defining positional-only parameters. However, some built-in functions have positional-only parameters (e.g. abs()).
> - keyword-only: specifies an argument that can be supplied only by keyword. Keyword-only parameters can be defined by including a single var-positional parameter or bare `*` in the parameter list of the function definition before them, for example kw_only1 and kw_only2 in the following:
>
>   `def func(arg, *, kw_only1, kw_only2): ...`

In other sense, "positional" would also be always true -- since keyword arguments are evaluated as positional arguments "behind the scenes". From the [Python language reference (Calls)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If keyword arguments are present, they are first converted to positional arguments, as follows [...]

The same [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) also give an example of positional but not keyword parameters:

> **CPython implementation detail:** An implementation may provide built-in functions whose positional parameters do not have names, even if they are ‘named’ for the purpose of documentation, and which therefore cannot be supplied by keyword. In CPython, this is the case for functions implemented in C that use `PyArg_ParseTuple()` to parse their arguments.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe if you want *default* arguments, you should add this

```
def fun(a=1,b=1)
       return a+b
```

so if you call fun without an argument, the default will make the code not error

```
>>> fun()
2
```

Comment: How does this address the OP's question?